# Keybindings with ZSH

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

Can anyone tell me how to move back a word in ZSH? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> will move back a character but not an entire word.

For instance a log command like this:

```
knife zero bootstrap mbigglesworth@10.10.1.108 --sudo-preserve-home --ssh-user mbigglesworth --sudo --policy-name linux_mint_wkstn -N linuxmint-vm -VV
```

...is painful to get to the middle of!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ESCAPE+b` or `ESCAPE+f` to move back one word or forward one word respectively

EDIT

The mentioned above are the defaults(as far as I'm concerned)

@TyMac mentions that the defaults are uppercase in his system though (ESCAPE-B, ESCAPE-F)

You may perfectly set them manually by inserting the following lines in your zshrc

```
bindkey "^[b" backward-word 
bindkey "^[f" forward-word
```

in case you don't like the defaults you may set it to some different key combo using this same syntax (I would suggest that it's preferable to use the defaults though but that's just personal opinion)

Comment: that's strange. could you please try running these commands and try that again? if it works you may add them to your zshrc:
    `bindkey "^[b" backward-word`
    `bindkey "^[f" forward-word`
you might also try to run `bindkey | egrep '(backward|forward)-word'` and see if they are already bound to something. what do you get?

Comment: also, what version of zsh are you using? `zsh --version`
if you are using the mac system zsh you might want to consider downloading a more updated version. recommended way of doing this is with [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) `brew install zsh`

Comment: zsh 5.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0)

Comment: bindkey | egrep '(backward|forward)-word'                                                                                = "^[B" backward-word - capital B :)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to move back and forward one word.

It does, however, depend heavily on your configuration. Read more [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/zsh#Key_bindings).

A list of other handy default keybindings is [here](http://www.geekmind.net/2011/01/shortcuts-to-improve-your-bash-zsh.html)

Comment: CTRL + the left or right arrow key? This is not working on my Mac. I have the default oh-my-zsh zshrc profile. Is there something I need to add?